# Migration - How to add a UNIQUE constraint to an already populated table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have a technicians table which consists only of name and timestamps columns in production, but now I need to use it as a devise model.

```
 class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of   :name
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
 end
```

Using `'rails generate devise technician'` led me to a migration with all that is necessary to make my technician model a devise model.

```
class AddDeviseToTechnicians < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:technicians) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
    end
  end
end
```

But I can't migrate since email is a '`unique: true`' column, nor drop my technicians table. What should I do?

I was thinking of setting the email field of each technician as: `name_attribute + "@email.com"`, but what's the best way to do this? 
I'm using a MYSQL database.

Comment: Check this one [on Device gem Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address), you can only use name instead of using email and username as they described in the link.

Comment: Though I suspect you rather need not "name or email", but "name only", that case is covered in a different guide: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address